# Is there a way to protect a git branch locally?

Tags: git

I'm evaluating someone else's git repository and I don't want to make accidental committed changes.

Is there a way to protect a branch locally just by using 'plain Git'? For example by preventing commit to particular branch?

I only need this to affect my local clone.

No Github or other git hosting service features should be involved. I want this to be as portab as possible.

Comment: You can certainly create a `pre-commit` hook that would fail when on a certain branch. But you could also just check out a new branch so that if your fingers twitch and somehow manage to type `git commit` by accident that your commits will be on a new branch.

Comment: If you cloned a repo, you will also have a copy of the remote state, so if you commit you can easily switch back to that.

Comment: Simply checkout a new branch if you are not confident to make changes on the same branch.

Comment: Thing is you can always revert a commit back even if you made an commit accidentally in original branch. What you should make sure is that you are not reverting published commit to a remote if you are working on same branch. so once your work is done in the new branch then you can merge or rebase that branch to the orginal branch.  Nothing out of the blue is needed.

Comment: You could also just remove the remotes, so that even if you do commit something you wouldn't be able to push it back upstream.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a [git hook](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks).
Place the following script into `.git/hooks/pre-commit` :

```bash
#!/bin/bash

current_branch="$(git branch --show-current)"
for protected_branch in "main" "other_branch_you_want_protected"; do
    if [[ "$protected_branch" == "$current_branch" ]]; then
        echo "ERROR: local branch $current_branch is protected" 
        exit 1
    fi
done

exit 0
```

On Linux, don't forget to `chmod +x` the script file.

Comment: I think a pre-commit hook is "overkill".  The whole POINT of a version control tool like Git is to "track changes".  The first line of defense is simply "don't commit anything".  Since it's a local repo, that should be easy.  If the OP somehow makes a commit they don't like, it will be obvious in Git history, and they can always revert it.  Finally, "protecting the baseline" with a new, temporary branch is probably a better solution than writing a pre-commit hook...

Comment: @paulsm4: While I agree in general, there might be usecases for this, e.g. if the checkout sits on a network share or something like this. OP deserves an answer that is not just *don't do that*.

Answer (score 4):

If it's your local clone, that's your repository. You've fetched history from their repository into yours and are evaluating the fetched history.

There's no need to protect anything, just don't push. Seems safe to say they're not going to unintentionally fetch. If you want to prevent perhaps-reflexive pushes you can

```
git config remote.origin.pushurl "You really didn't want to do that."
```

The only way anything you do affects their repository is if you push or they fetch (new or changed) refs and any new history.